# Почему подвисает прелоадер?

Tags: javascript, gif

Использую на сайте gif-прелоадер. Пока прелоадер крутится - на страницу динамически ajax-запросами загружается контент. Проблема в том что мой gif-прелоадер крутится только когда хочет. В основном он просто зависает в одном положении и не движется пока страница не прогрузится. С чем это может быть связано? Думал что дело в размере и пробовал ужимать саму gif'ку и пробовать другие. В итоге файл весит уже около 1Кб и всё равно зависает.

Comment: а ajax-ом много грузится? Когда вы что-то делаете с DOM-ом, у вас блокируется весь поток, и тот же лоадер может зависать из-за этого

Comment: ajax-ом грузится большинство информации которую я позже javascript-ом кидаю в DOM

Comment: Дело в дом манипуляциях, можете даже проверить: уберите ajax загрузку, или просто ничего не делайте при получении данных и посмотрите за лоадером, Он должен на ура работать

Comment: И еще, приведите кусочек кода, как именно вы манипулируете домом и вставляете туда данные

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы делаете синхронные AJAX запросы.

К примеру если вы используете jQuery, то обратите внимание, что у вас не используется опция `async:false (default: true).` Когда вы используете синхронные запросы - основной цикл исполнения блокируется как и вся анимация и рендеринг, до тех пор пока не будут получены данные от сервера. Если всё-же ваши запросы асинхронные, то скорее всего действительно - вы перегружаете браузерную логику и она просто не успевает уделить процессорное время для анимации. К примеру вы сортируете большие массивы данных прямо в браузере и в этот же момент пытаетесь их отобразить.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь все современные браузеры сейчас превентят синхронные XHR запросы и кидают ворнинг в консоль